# The handle is invalid with python patoolib executable file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, unrar

My python file is working fine

```
import patoolib patoolib.extract_archive("test.7z")
```

But when I use pyinstaller  to make an executable  on windows I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "patol.py", line 2, in <module>
    patoolib.extract_archive("test.7z")
  File "patoolib\__init__.py", line 684, in extract_archive
    return _extract_archive(archive, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, outdir=outdir, program=program)
  File "patoolib\__init__.py", line 484, in _extract_archive
    run_archive_cmdlist(cmdlist, verbosity=verbosity)
  File "patoolib\__init__.py", line 421, in run_archive_cmdlist
    return util.run_checked(cmdlist, verbosity=verbosity, **runkwargs)
  File "patoolib\util.py", line 224, in run_checked
    retcode = run(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "patoolib\util.py", line 216, in run
    res = subprocess.call(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "subprocess.py", line 349, in call
  File "subprocess.py", line 829, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1252, in _get_handles
OSError: [WinError 6] Descripteur non valide
```

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding:

```py
kwargs['stdin'] =subprocess.PIPE 

kwargs['sterr'] =subprocess.STDOUT
```

in this file for python 3.9: `Python39-32\Lib\site-packages\patoolib\util.py` (lines 215 to 217)